# Excel VBA email creation, setting focus back to input box

Tags: vba, excel, email, excel-2010

the code below is creating an email, whilst searching through folders and attaching the relevant docs.

I have coded it to check whether the user has sent the email or closed it. I have put it so an input box gets displayed when the user closes the email. What i would like to happen is when the email gets closed, is the InputBox is set to focus, and after a reason why the email was sent have been entered then go back to the email to click on don't save draft.

Or even have the input box display after the email has been closed, after the save without changed dialog box.

Userform Code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim itmevt As New CMailItemEvents

Private Sub btnEMSent_Click()
Dim i, j, lastG, lastD As Long
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sFName As String, colFiles As New Collection
Dim myDir As String, ChDir As String, attName As New Collection, attName2 As String
Dim dte As String
Dim greet As String, cntName As String, SigString As String, Signature As String

lastG = Sheets("File Locations").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

SigString = "H:\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\"
If Dir(SigString, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    SigString = SigString & Dir$(SigString & "*.htm")
Else:
    SigString = ""
End If
Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(SigString).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).readall

If Me.cmbMonth.Value = "" Then
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Visible = True
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Caption = "Payment Month Required!"
    Me.cmbMonth.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.txtbxYear.Value = "" Then
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Visible = True
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Caption = "Payment Year Required!"
    Me.txtbxYear.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.cmbSubbie.Value = "" Then
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Visible = True
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Caption = "Sub-Contractor Required!"
    Me.cmbSubbie.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 1 To lastG
lookupVal = Sheets("File Locations").Cells(i, "B") ' value to find
If Dir(lookupVal, vbDirectory) = "" Then
Else
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set itmevt.itm = OutMail

    dte = Me.cmbMonth.Value & " " & Me.txtbxYear.Text
    myDir = lookupVal 'Set Dir to search
    ChDir = (myDir & "\" & Me.cmbSubbie.Value & "\Remittance\") 'Change to that dir
    sFName = Dir(ChDir & "*" & dte & "*")  'Set Search spec

    While InStr(sFName, dte)
        colFiles.Add (ChDir & sFName)
        attName.Add (sFName)
        sFName = Dir
    Wend
End If
Next i

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    If Me.txtbxSubNAME.Value <> "" Then
        cntName = " " & Me.txtbxSubNAME.Value & ","
    Else
        cntName = ","
    End If
    If Time < TimeValue("12:00:00") Then
        greet = "Good Morning" & cntName
    Else
        greet = "Good Afternoon" & cntName
    End If
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
            .Attachments.Add colFiles(i)
            attName2 = attName(i) & "<br>" & attName2
        Next i
    End If
    .To = Me.txtbxSubEMAIL.Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Me.cmbMonth.Value & "'s Remittances"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLbody = "<HTML><BODY></BODY></HTML>" & .HTMLbody & Signature
    .Display True
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

In the class module CMailItemEvents:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBox _
            Lib "User64" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
                (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                ByVal lpText As String, _
                ByVal lpCaption As String, _
                ByVal wType As Long) _
            As Long
    Private Sub itm_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim blnSent As Boolean
    Dim lastG As Long
    Dim myValue As Variant

        lastG = Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

       On Error Resume Next
       blnSent = itm.Sent
       If Err.Number = 0 Then
        myValue = inputBox("Why was " & usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie & " Remittance E-Mail not sent?", "Remittance Error")
        Sheets("Report").Range("A" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.Value
        Sheets("Report").Range("B" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbMonth.Text & " " & usrFrmEMAIL.txtbxYear.Text
        Sheets("Report").Range("C" & lastG).Value = Now
        AppActivate (myValue.ActiveExplorer.CurrentItem)
        Sheets("Report").Range("D" & lastG).Value = myValue
        Exit Sub
       Else
        Sheets("Report").Range("A" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.Value
        Sheets("Report").Range("B" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbMonth.Text & " " & usrFrmEMAIL.txtbxYear.Text
        Sheets("Report").Range("C" & lastG).Value = Now
       End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: can you clarify your question, exactly, what you are stuck on etc? it's hard to understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for taking so long to get back, i've been away on holiday.

I managed to figure out how to get this to work.

Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib _
 "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function AttachThreadInput Lib "user32" _
(ByVal idAttach As Long, ByVal idAttachTo As Long, _
 ByVal fAttach As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
 (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsIconic Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
 (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName _
  As Long, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Const SW_SHOW = 5
Const SW_RESTORE = 9

Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem

Function ForceForegroundWindow(ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
    Dim ThreadID1 As Long
    Dim ThreadID2 As Long
    Dim nRet As Long

    If hWnd = GetForegroundWindow Then
        ForceForegroundWindow = True
    Else
        ThreadID1 = GetWindowThreadProcessId( _
          GetForegroundWindow, ByVal 0&)
        ThreadID2 = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ByVal 0&)
        If ThreadID1 <> ThreadID2 Then
            AttachThreadInput ThreadID1, ThreadID2, True
            nRet = SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)
            AttachThreadInput ThreadID1, ThreadID2, False
        Else
            nRet = SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)
        End If
        If IsIconic(hWnd) Then
            ShowWindow hWnd, SW_RESTORE
        Else
            ShowWindow hWnd, SW_SHOW
        End If
        ForceForegroundWindow = CBool(nRet)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub itm_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim blnSent As Boolean
Dim lastG As Long, currentrow As Integer
Dim myValue As String
Dim bOK As Boolean
Dim idx As Long

idx = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListIndex
lastG = Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

On Error Resume Next
blnSent = itm.Sent
If Err.Number = 0 Then
itm.Close olDiscard
ForceForegroundWindow FindWindowA(0, Application.Caption)
    Do
    myValue = inputBox("Why was " & usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie & "'s Remittance E-Mail not sent?", "Remittance Error")
        If StrPtr(myValue) = 0 Then
            bOK = False
            MsgBox "You cannot just press Cancel!" & vbLf & vbLf & "A reason is needed for not sending the email.", vbCritical
        ElseIf myValue = "" Then
            bOK = False
            MsgBox "You didn't enter anything, but pressed OK" & vbLf & vbLf & "A reason is needed for not sending the email.", vbExclamation
        ElseIf Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myValue, " ", "")) = 0 Then
            bOK = False
            MsgBox "You only entered spaces!" & vbLf & vbLf & "A reason is needed for not sending the email.", vbExclamation
        Else
            bOK = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until bOK = True
    Sheets("Report").Range("A" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.Value
    Sheets("Report").Range("B" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbMonth.Text & " " & usrFrmEMAIL.txtbxYear.Text
    Sheets("Report").Range("C" & lastG).Value = Now
    Sheets("Report").Range("D" & lastG).Value = myValue
    If idx <> usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListCount - 1 Then
        usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListIndex = idx + 1
    Else
        usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListIndex = 0
    End If
Else
    For currentrow = 6 To lastG
        Sheets("Report").Range("A" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.Value
        Sheets("Report").Range("B" & lastG).Value = usrFrmEMAIL.cmbMonth.Text & " " & usrFrmEMAIL.txtbxYear.Text
        Sheets("Report").Range("C" & lastG).Value = Now
        Sheets("Report").Range("D" & lastG).Value = "Sent"
    Next
    If idx <> usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListCount - 1 Then
        usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListIndex = idx + 1
    Else
        usrFrmEMAIL.cmbSubbie.ListIndex = 0
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

UserForm Code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim itmevt As New CMailItemEvents
Private Sub btnCreateEmail_Click()
Dim i, j, lastG, lastD As Long
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sFName As String, colFiles As New Collection
Dim myDir As String, ChDir As String, attName As New Collection, attName2 As String
Dim dte As String
Dim greet As String, cntName As String, SigString As String, Signature As String

lastG = Sheets("File Locations").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

SigString = "H:\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\"
If Dir(SigString, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    SigString = SigString & Dir$(SigString & "*.htm")
Else:
    SigString = ""
End If
Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(SigString).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).readall

If Me.cmbMonth.Value = "" Then
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Visible = True
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Caption = "Required!"
    Me.cmbMonth.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.txtbxYear.Value = "" Then
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Visible = True
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Caption = "Required!"
    Me.txtbxYear.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.cmbSubbie.Value = "" Then
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Visible = True
    Me.lblErrorMsg.Caption = "Required!"
    Me.cmbSubbie.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 1 To lastG
lookupVal = Sheets("File Locations").Cells(i, "B") ' value to find
If Dir(lookupVal, vbDirectory) = "" Then
Else
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set itmevt.itm = OutMail

    dte = Me.cmbMonth.Value & " " & Me.txtbxYear.Text
    myDir = lookupVal 'Set Dir to search
    ChDir = (myDir & "\" & Me.cmbSubbie.Value & "\***\") 'Change to that dir
    sFName = Dir(ChDir & "*" & dte & "*")  'Set Search spec

    While InStr(sFName, dte)
        colFiles.Add (ChDir & sFName)
        attName.Add (sFName)
        sFName = Dir
    Wend
End If
Next i

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    If Me.txtbxSubNAME.Value <> "" Then
        cntName = " " & Me.txtbxSubNAME.Value & ","
    Else
        cntName = ","
    End If
    If Time < TimeValue("12:00:00") Then
        greet = "Good Morning" & cntName
    Else
        greet = "Good Afternoon" & cntName
    End If
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
            .Attachments.Add colFiles(i)
            attName2 = attName(i) & "<br>" & attName2
        Next i
    End If
    .To = Me.txtbxSubEMAIL.Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Me.cmbMonth.Value & "'s "
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLbody = "<HTML><BODY STYLE='font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & greet & "<br><br>" & "Thank for your . Please see the attached remittances." & "<br><br>" & "<b>" & attName2 & "</b>" _
    & "<br>" & "Please submit if you are required to do so. In this email, could you please copy in:" & "<br><br>" & _
    "" & "<br><br>" & _
    "<b>" & "Please note: " & "</b>" & "If you need to supply a matching invoice and we do not receive one, your payment's will be held." & "<br><br>" & "Kind regards," & "</BODY></HTML>" & .HTMLbody & Signature
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0



Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```